# docker build using buildkit fails with a strange error

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

I am trying to build a docker image using docker buildkit, but something goes wrong, and the building process fails:

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 39B                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /home/docker/100000.100000/tmp/buildkit-mount158723236/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

That is how the `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
# docker/dockerfile:1

FROM alpine

RUN mkdir -p /dir/a/b/c
```

Docker version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
```

The same works on other machines, so I suppose that it should be some local problems. But what could it be?

Comment: what if add `-f ${absolute path of dockerfile}`?

Comment: @LeiYang: I think I already found what was the problem; it was fedora where I ran it, and docker there seems to have no buildkit support at all